# Heroku Toolbelt Stuck Administering Deleted App

Tags: meteorite, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to deploy a meteorite project that I'm working on. I messed up a few times, but for the moment I keep getting:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git
Setting config vars and restarting cryptic-wave-7090... failed
 !    App not found
```

No matter how many times I create a new app, it tries to apply that to one that I deleted a while ago. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and the way I resolved it was by using the destroy command. In order to destroy cryptic-wave-7090 for example, use the following:

```
heroku destroy cryptic-wave-7090
```

Comment: If you look at the title of the question which is "Heroku Toolbelt Stuck Administering Deleted App" emphasis on the delete, you can see that the app has already been destroyed (deleted), but the toolbelt is hanging on to a reference to the app. This seems to happen if you delete an existing app on Heroku.com but you have a reference to it in the toolbelt (possibly from creating it using the toolbelt), I looked for a command to sync Heroku.com with the toolbelt but found none, Destroy was the only command that worked.